# How To Call JFrame from another Java class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am trying to do a simple Jform and call it from another class.
I want to use this Jframe in a server client application, but I don't know how to open the JFrame class from another class.

Like user has to chose

1- to open Jframe.

2- To Exit.

So What am I doing wrong?

Below are the codes:

Jframe Class named Calculas.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class Calculas extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Calculas
     */
    public Calculas() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        a1Text = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        a2Text = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        answer = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(a1Text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(a2Text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                        .addComponent(answer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(113, 113, 113)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addContainerGap(86, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(a1Text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(a2Text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(answer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(140, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
int a;
a = Integer.parseInt(a1Text.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(a2Text.getText());
answer.setText("Answer" + a);

        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Calculas().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField a1Text;
    private javax.swing.JTextField a2Text;
    private javax.swing.JLabel answer;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Test Class named Test.java

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Calculas CAL = new Calculas();
    CAL.Calculus();
}
}
```

Comment: Just run the calculas class. It has already a main method.

Comment: @ZouZou What if the OP wants to include the Calculas class in another class and needs the reference to the Calculas class for other things, like setting/getting properties? Calling Calculas.main directly isn't going to achieve this - just saying

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok, got it =). @JonathanLopez You could just copy/paste the main method below the line `Calculas CAL = new Calculas();` and change the line `new Calculas().setVisible(true);` to `CAL.setVisible(true);` of the Calculas class (to be able to have the Nimbus look).

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: comes asks goes...never comes back....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Forgive me if this is naive, as Im not anything of a Java programmer...
But isnt it just because you need to set visible?

```
Calculas CAL = new Calculas();
CAL.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of `Calculas` doesn't show (`setVisible`) the frame.

If you want to interact with the `Calculas` class in this manner, you should also be calling `CAL.setVisible(true)`

Also, by convention, all Java instance variables, should start with a lower case character and use camelCase conventions

Comment: Actually it has already a main in the Calculas class which shows the frame.

Comment: But the OP isn't calling Calculas.main, they're constructing the class directly. Generally speaking, you should try and construct classes via the main method, unless your trying to test the whole application, which is unspecified in the question ;)

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I think that the OP is a beginner because he just copy/pasted the code and tried to launch it with a new class that contains a main.

Answer (score 3):

In it's current form of your code, you can call the main method of your `Calculas` class in `Test` class or move the code to the `Test` class.

Warning: Extending JFrame is not a good Idea.

First alternative: You don't need to extend JFrame in Test

```
  public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Calculas.main(new String[0]);
    }
   }
```

You haven't mentioned in your question how you want to be able to chose close or open, in console or in another `JFrame` or something...

**Second Alternative:**

But If I were you I could do something like this: wrap the code for look and feel in a separate method and call this from `Test`' s main.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class Calculas extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Calculas
     */
    public Calculas() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        a1Text = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        a2Text = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        answer = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(a1Text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(a2Text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                        .addComponent(answer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(113, 113, 113)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addContainerGap(86, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(a1Text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(a2Text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(answer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(140, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
int a;
a = Integer.parseInt(a1Text.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(a2Text.getText());
answer.setText("Answer" + a);

        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        
    public static setNimbusFeel(){
          /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculas.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField a1Text;
    private javax.swing.JTextField a2Text;
    private javax.swing.JLabel answer;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

And test class like this:

```
  public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Calculas cal=new Calculas();
        //</editor-fold>
        Calculas.setNimbusFeel();
       /* Create and display the form */
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            new Calculas().setVisible(true);
          }
       });
      }
     }
```

Like this:

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a basic structure you can use:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;



class MyGui {

    private JFrame window = new JFrame("This is the title");

    public MyGui() {
        initComponents();

        window.setBounds(100, 50, 600, 400); //location, size
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void initComponents() {
        Container cp = window.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout() );
        cp.add(new JLabel("Hello world") );
    }
}


public class MyProg {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        new MyGui();
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in separate files:

MyGui.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyGui {

    private JFrame window = new JFrame("This is the title");

    public MyGui() {
        initComponents();

        window.setBounds(100, 50, 600, 400); //location, size
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void initComponents() {
        Container cp = window.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout() );
        cp.add(new JLabel("Hello world") );
    }
}
```

MyProg.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyProg {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        new MyGui();
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Calculas CAL = new Calculas();
  CAL.Calculus();
```

maybe, `CAL.Calculas();` I dont know java but I realized that, sorry about my english:)