# How to call JFrame from another Java class [Netbeans]

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I know it has been posted before, but I was not able to achieve any results so I am asking for help.

I am trying to call my `JFrame` class to my main class that will be setting up the Comm port. The frame is created using the design in the Netbeans software. 
**My question is why is my main Java file not able to open the frame that is created in another class?**

Below are the shortened codes:

**The main class is `SerialTest`**

```
package javaapplication1;

import javaapplication1.RCDA_JFrame;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SerialTest extends JFrame implements SerialPortEventListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                JFrame RCDA_JFrame = new JFrame();
                RCDA_JFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**And my GUI class is `RCDA_JFrame`**

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.io.IOException;
//import java.io.OutputStream;
import javaapplication1.SerialTest;

public class RCDA_JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    //private OutputStream SerialOut;
    public RCDA_JFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RCDA_JFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: *"I know it has been posted before,.."*  Link to it/them. *"..but I was not able to achieve any results so I am asking for help."*  What is it that makes you think we can help you better than those questions could, especially when we don't know why they did **not** work for you?

Comment: I'm only using one JFrame.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018857/how-to-call-jframe-from-another-java-class?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: *"I'm only using one JFrame."*  And yet, both the classes extend `JFrame` ..  Where are those links?

Comment: Where is the `initComponents()` method?

Comment: I imported the JFrame file and I followed the same steps for the main function by setting up the JFrame and then setting it visible. 
I am only getting a JFrame with nothing inside.

Comment: Andrew, I tried not including the JFrame but it didn't change anything and I just pasted it without deleting that. I edited my comment.

Comment: Jonah, I erased the 600 lines of code that was unnecessary to put on here that contains my UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, only one class (the GUI class) should extend JFrame. However, this is not causing the problem. Secondly, neither class is ever instantiated even though both extend `JFrame` (which generally implies that one should be instantiated). Thirdly, you should only have one `main` method throughout an entire application. Fourthly, not entirely sure what the `main()` method within the GUI class is doing -- why does it create an RCDA_JFrame (I though the Serial class was supposed to do that, based on the title question), and why does it do this within a separate thread? Finally, make sure that you are setting the JFrame's size (Though you may already be doing this within the `initComponents` method.)

Here's some basic code that will allow you to create and access a custom JFrame from another class:

**Start class (This is the main class)**

```
public class Start{
    private static CustomJFrame myFrame;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        myFrame = new CustomJFrame();
        //you can edit myFrame's properties here.
    }
}
```

**CustomJFrame class (the JFrame class)**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class CustomJFrame extends JFrame{
    public CustomJFrame(){
        //set its size in px.
        setSize(200,200);
        //center it on screen.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //give it a title.
        setTitle("My JFrame");
        //set the close operation.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //make it visible.
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Tested and works just fine.

Comment: Nerdizzle, it was able to open when I comment out the setLocaton(null); !

Comment: it's `setLocationRelativeTo(null)`, not `setLocation(null)`. `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` merely centers the window on the screen. `setLocation(null)` would (at least I would imagine) return a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing something like this. No need for two `main` methods.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SerialTest{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(RCDA_JFrame::new);
    }
}
```

And this

```
public class RCDA_JFrame extends JFrame {

    public RCDA_JFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void initComponents(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jonah, just letting you know, I am unable to edit anything in the initComponents() because Netbeans automatically creates the code for my corresponding GUI. Thanks though!

Comment: You don't have to. I just put that code there to post a working example.